# Insert arbitrary value and select in the same statement MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do something like

```
INSERT INTO tbl_order_detail (key_order,key_product,fld_unit_price,fld_quantity) 
VALUES (<value1>, <value2>,
SELECT fld_unit_price,fld_quantity FROM tbl_product WHERE key_product = <value2>);
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: Not possible in MySQL. You need two statements: first run the `insert` statement, then run the `select`

Comment: Or is the other way around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_order_detail 
    (key_order,key_product,fld_unit_price,fld_quantity)
SELECT <value1>, <value2>, fld_unit_price,fld_quantity 
FROM tbl_product 
WHERE key_product = <value2>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     INSERT
INTO tbl_order_detail
  (
    key_order,
    key_product,
    fld_unit_price,
    fld_quantity
  )
SELECT 
    <value1>,
    <value2>,
    fld_unit_price,
    fld_quantity
  FROM tbl_product
  WHERE key_product = <value2>
;
```